# Windows 8 not accepting password for a while

Tags: login, windows-8

I recently upgraded from windows 8 Consumer Preview to Windows 8 Pro (RTM through dreamspark premium), and have the following issue:

When I attempt to log in after a restart, it often takes a while (~3 minutes) for the computer to accept the password (Each try goes relatively quickly, a few seconds at most before telling me I have an incorrect password).

I changed the password, and this issue is unresolved (the old password came with the upgrade).

What could be doing this?

Comment: Network drivers?

Comment: @RandolphWest no domain. Also, shows up without being connected to a network (or with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the input keyboard when the computer boots up is not English (what it would need to be to accept the password). Attempting to try with a different account reset the keyboard setting to English, allowing it to work.